# How to get output as 'NA' if date is Null and datetime format if not null?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Here I had a query,

```
SELECT MIN(DATE)  FROM tableA
```

Here,If the date value is Null then it should display 'NA',

```
SELECT isnull(convert(varchar(10),MIN(DATE)),'NA')  FROM tableA
```

It worked for the case MIN(DATE) is null but if it not null the ouput is getting in different format like `May 11` etc How can I fix this?

Comment: Which format would you want the result ? also you have to update the title as 'NA' not your issue :)

Comment: Also take a look at this, you might be able to solve this yourself [SQL Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not store the format of the date/time values, they are stored as integers.

`CONVERT()` has a third parameter which defines the format (built in) of the output for date types. The default depends on your configuration and server settings

More info in BOL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MIN([date]), 120), 'NA') FROM tableA
```

Alternatively you can use `FORMAT` in newer versions (2012+) to specify a custom format.

Again, more info in BOL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql

```
SELECT COALESCE(FORMAT(MIN([date]), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'NA') FROM tableA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @day TABLE ([DATE] DATE)
INSERT INTO @day
SELECT '2017-02-04' Union all
SELECT '2017-05-05' Union all
SELECT  NULL    Union all
SELECT '2017-06-06' Union all
SELECT '2017-08-08' 
SELECT [DATE],ISNULL(NULLIF(CONVERT(varchar(10),MIN([DATE])),'1900-01-01'),'NA') as ConvertedColumn from @day
GROUP by [DATE]
```

OutPut shows the if the date column contains minimum date value as Null then it shows AS 'NA' and shows next minimum date values from table

```
DATE        |ConvertedColumn
----------------------------
NULL        | NA
2017-02-04  |2017-02-04
2017-05-05  |2017-05-05
2017-06-06  |2017-06-06
2017-08-08  |2017-08-08
```